# Itertools chain behaves differently in Cython

Tags: python, cython, python-itertools

I have two sets of items, A and B, of which A is expected to be larger. I want all unordered tuples of a given size from A U B, which contain at least one element from B.

My approach is to take each element of B, take the `product` of it with all (k-1)-tuple `combinations` of A, and then add the element to A so that it's included in combinations with the remaining members of B. Then I `chain` those products together.

I have it working in Python, but when I put it into Cython, the behavior changes. (In this example I'm just doing pairs but I would want to generalize up to a 5-tuple. My example sets have 4 and 2 items but I would expect hundreds - which is why I'm using generators rather than just expanding out the tuples up front.)

The Python version (desired behavior):

```
from itertools import combinations, chain, product

def get_colder_python():
    inventory = {"hat","shoes","shirt","socks"}
    add_items = {"pants","jacket"}
    combo_chain = []
    for a in add_items:
        next_iterator = product([a],combinations(inventory,1))
        combo_chain.append((x,*y) for x,y in next_iterator)
        inventory.add(a)    
    combos = chain.from_iterable(combo_chain)
    return list(combos)

print(get_colder_python())
```

Result:

```
[('jacket', 'shoes'), ('jacket', 'shirt'), ('jacket', 'hat'), ('jacket', 'socks'), ('pants', 'shirt'), ('pants', 'jacket'), ('pants', 'hat'), ('pants', 'shoes'), ('pants', 'socks')]
```

The Cython version:

```
%%cython

from itertools import chain,product,combinations

cdef get_colder_cython():
    inventory = {"hat","shoes","shirt","socks"}
    add_items = {"pants","jacket"}
    combo_chain = []
    for a in add_items:
        next_iterator = product([a],combinations(inventory,1))
        combo_chain.append((x,*y) for x,y in next_iterator)
        inventory.add(a)
    combos = chain.from_iterable(combo_chain)
    return list(combos)

print(get_colder_cython())
```

Result

```
[('pants', 'shirt'), ('pants', 'jacket'), ('pants', 'hat'), ('pants', 'shoes'), ('pants', 'socks')]
```

It's only getting the second iterator from the chain.

My workaround for now is "don't use Cython for this", and I understand that itertools are well-optimized so that Cython shouldn't bring a big speed boost, BUT I'd like to understand why it's behaving differently.

Comment: Running your first block in python 3.3, I get the second (shorter) set of results. Could you include the versions of each interpreter you're using?

Comment: @c2huc2hu you sure about that? I can only go back to Python 3.4 easily, but it fails with `SyntaxError: can use starred expression only as assignment target`. I could be wrong though - as I say, I didn't manage to test it myself

Comment: @JeremySadler - there's definitely some long-standing bugs in Cython about scope in generator expressions. I can't _immediately_ see how these apply here, but I suspect that's the issue here. It works for me if you swap the generator expression for a list comprehension

Comment: @DavidW That did it, thank you! For my learning - is the list comprehension still doing the lazy generation when I use it in a loop? Or is it grinding out the full list when I use the expression?

Comment: @c2huc2hu I'm using Python 3.8.8, IPython 7.21.0, in Jupyter Notebook server 6.3.0. I can probably dig up my Cython version, but I installed it last week so it's whatever's recent on conda. My C compiler I got from Visual Studio Community Edition.

Comment: The list comprehension is creating the full list (rather than doing it lazily). Unfortunately, my suspicion is that this is what makes it work here.

Comment: Whoops, ignore my earlier comment. I ran it again on 3.7 and got the same results as OP. Not sure what env I was using before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to give a bit more detail: generator variable scope is [a long-standing bug on Cython](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/1159).

The line that will behave differently is

```
((x,*y) for x,y in next_iterator)
```

In both cases it's lazily executed. In Python it looks up `next_iterator`, stores a reference to it, and initializes the generator expression with that reference.

In Cython it does almost nothing when the generator expression is created - instead `next_iterator` is only looked up when the expression is executed. At which point it's already been reassigned to multiple times.

My suggestion is to use list comprehension, since these are executed instantly on creation. But that obviously loses the lazy benefit. A nested generator function might also work:

```
def gen(next_iterator):
    yield from ((x,*y) for x,y in next_iterator)
combo_chain.append(gen)
```

Although creating a function isn't that cheap, so you may find that bad for performance.

Comment: Oh, geeze, that bug's over 10 years old!

Comment: It's surprisingly complicated to fix, while preserving all the various optimisations that Cython does to loops.